# Dragula - How do I modify a variable based on the order of the elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm using [dragula](http://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) to create a drag and drop exercise.

How could I set a Javascript variable when one of the elements is moved? Essentially, I want to know how the elements are ordered on the screen.

See example [drag and drop here](http://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would listen to the `dragend` event. Whenever it is triggered you can iterate through the items and push them to an array. Afterwards you can validate if the order is correct.

```
// ...
.on("dragend", function(el, target, src) {
    elems = []; // reset elems
    $(".elem").each(function(idx, elem) {
        elems.push($(elem).text());
    });

    // validate that elems are in correct order
    // ...
});
// ...
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frncsdrk/pkkep679/) for a working example.

You can find a list of all events, their parameters and description in the [docs](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#drakeon-events).

Comment: Could you put the files into a fiddle or a gist?

Comment: Sure, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/599vj7mv/), although now I've moved it to fiddle now dragula isn't working at all! (Can you tell that I'm really new to JavaScript?) I really appreciate your help frnscdrk.

Comment: The external resources can only be js and css files. There is no upload possible. So if you need libraries like dragula you have to link to a cdn. I linked dragula accordingly and updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/599vj7mv/1/). In the js area you seem to reference other resources. If they aren't needed to solve the problem remove them, if they are include them as external resources over a cdn. Also you reference html elements you have not included in the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a bit of a mess. I checked your updated fiddle and couldn't see any differences... am I missing something? I've cleaned up my css and removed those html elements that weren't included. Not sure about the JS resources - I've taken this code from one of dragula's demos so don't understand what each bit really does...

Comment: I just wanted to pop back in and say thanks frncsdrk - I figured out why my project wasn't working and have now made great progress thanks to your help.